# Finding primary domain using Python

Tags: python, subdomain

I am trying to find a method to find the primary domain for a website.

For example: if you visit [www.yalochat.com](http://www.yalochat.com) the browser automatically changes the address to [www.yalo.com](http://www.yalo.com). Therefore:

Input: [www.yalochat.com](http://www.yalochat.com)
Output: [www.yalo.com](http://www.yalo.com)

Input: [www.yalo.com](http://www.yalo.com)
Output: [www.yalo.com](http://www.yalo.com)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: what have you attempted so far? context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the requests module as follows:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.yalochat.com')
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(r.url)
```